# cannot invoke initializer for Unmanaged<AnyObject>? with no arguments in swift

Tags: ios, swift, base64, rsa

what I want is to convert `RSA` `Sec` key into `base64` encoded string with swift. so I `initialized` a variable like below,

```
var publicKeyBits = Unmanaged<AnyObject>?()
```

then it gives

> cannot invoke initializer for Unmanaged? with no arguments
>   in swift

I want to covert my `publickey` like below

```
var publicKeyBits = Unmanaged<AnyObject>?()
SecItemCopyMatching(queryAttrs, &publicKeyBits)

let opaqueBits = publicKeyBits?.toOpaque() 
let publicKeyData = Unmanaged<NSData>.fromOpaque(opaqueBits).takeUnretainedValue()

let publicKeyBase64 = publicKeyData.base64EncodedData(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions.Encoding64CharacterLineLength)
```

error. any idea of this.

Comment: @MartinR done, please check

Comment: @MartinR, tried it gives `-50` for the `status`

Comment: `-50` is "parameter error", which means that the query is not valid. That's a different problem.

Answer (score 1):

`SecItemCopyMatching` is declared as

```
public func SecItemCopyMatching(_ query: CFDictionary,
                               _ result: UnsafeMutablePointer<CFTypeRef?>?) -> OSStatus
```

so you have to pass the address of a `CFTypeRef?` as inout argument.
(In early Swift versions this function returned an unmanaged object,
that is no longer the case.)

You retrieve the item as a `CFTypeRef` (a typealias for `AnyObject`) and then cast it to the actual type. Example:

```
var result: CFTypeRef?
let status = SecItemCopyMatching(queryAttrs, &result)
if status == errSecSuccess {
    if let publicKeyData = result as? Data {
        let base64 = publicKeyData.base64EncodedString()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the initialization of Unmanaged class, there might be some initialization parameters.

```
var publicKeyBits = Unmanaged<AnyObject>("mykey")
```

Comment: [`Unmanaged`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/unmanaged)  has no (public) init methods at all.